# How I can go from a AppCompatActivity to ComposeActivity in Android app?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I got this message when i try use an `Intent`:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method pushWithTransition(Landroidx/navigation/NavBackStackEntry;)Landroidx/navigation/NavigatorState$OnTransitionCompleteListener; in class Landroidx/navigation/NavigatorState

Comment: Could you show ur code and what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, This is code what I use to go to ComposeActivity
var i = Intent(applicationContext,MenuActivity::class.java)
                            startActivity(i)